# DevExpress BaseLayoutItem Size

Tags: wpf, devexpress, actualwidth, actualheight

In WPF how can I find the size of a DevExpress `BaseLayoutItem`? It inherits from `ContentElement` so has no `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will post the answer to this question at:

[Actual size of a BaseLayoutItem](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q303651)